# How to use custom docker registry in my Vagrant file so that I can use custom image(Mysql/Redis) in the VM

Tags: vagrant, docker-registry

I have a Vagrant file with docker provisioner. Earlier I was using mysql image from the public docker registry. Now After our custom registry is created with mysql image in it, I need to use this registry in my vagrant file to pull images and run it in the VM. Please provide me some examples

Comment: When you say custom registry, are you referring to a private registry or the machine's local registry?

Answer (score 0):

## Private registry

To use a private registry, you use a different URI for the image name.

Public

```
docker pull centos
```

Private

```
docker pull 10.0.0.1:5000/centos:centos7
# or
docker pull myhostname.com/centos:centos7
```

My workflow looks kind of like this when I pull a public image, customize it, and then want to push it to a private repo:

```
docker pull centos
# do stuff to container...
docker commit [container-id] myregistry.internal/centos:centos7
```

Alternatively, I believe you can do this if you want to get the container into the private registry before you do stuff to it:

```
docker pull centos:centos7
docker tag centos:centos7 myregistry.internal/centos:centos7
docker push myregistry.internal/centos:centos7
```

## Local registry

If you just want to make some local changes to an image and then use those changes afterwards. Simply commit the change locally. I'd suggest changing the tag though to avoid confusion.

```
docker commit [container-id] centos:mycentos
```

Now you can just use the centos:mycentos image for starting your container.